# Running a script within a jquery model

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm using a jquery plugin ([jQuery Image Scale](http://imgscale.kjmeath.com/)) to resize my individual images on my page. A simple example:

```
 // HTML:     
 <div class='parent_container'>
      <img src='image.jpg' class='resize_image' />
 </div>
 <div class='parent_container'>
      <img src='image.jpg' class='resize_image' />
 </div>

 // CSS:
 .parent_container {
      width: 200px;
      padding: 200px;
 }

 // jQuery:
 $('.resize_image').imgscale({
    fade : 1000,
    scale : "fill"
 });
```

In a nutshell irrespective of what size the image is, it will "fill" the .parent_container and there will be no overflow. Based on the selector in the jQuery it will take all images and check the width/height of the parent container (.parent_container) and fill the container.

I have managed to get this to work, but for my example I have a "read more" button which when pressed, will open a jQuery dialog window and have the same image with the copy in there. I want to do the same with the images within the dialog window, but it appears that jQueryUI either adds or subtracts (or does something) with the image so although the script runs and adds the neccesary modifications to both the normal and dialog images, the styling for the image is broken, almost as if the dialog window removes the margin assigned by the script.

What I want to do now is to add the jQuery script above to the active dialog window after the window has loaded, that way it should re-apply the styling needed to get it to work. Here is sample HTML from my script:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

// Assign to all images with .resize_image as class
$('.resize_image').imgscale({
    fade : 1000,
    scale : "fill"
});

// Dialog box default properties (also, on open, re-assign the plugin to the all the images with the class .resize_image
var dialog_properties = {
    "width"   : "600",
    open    : function(event,ui) {
        $('.resize_image').imgscale({
            fade : 1000,
            scale : "fill"
        });
    }
};

var popup_to_open;

 // When I click the read more button, load the appropriate hidden container with it's content
$(".popup_content .big_button").click(function() {

    popup_to_open = $(this).attr("rel");

    $("div[rel='"+popup_to_open+"']").dialog(dialog_properties);
    return false;
});

 });
```

I effectively need to run the script after the model has loaded so that I can have the script add the neccesary styling.

My question is, the open: function() part above does not work, or if it does it's not doing the trick. Is there another way to do it (am I doing it wrong) and b) is there a more clean cut version of doing this without applying the script again each time someone clicks the dialog box (maybe isolate it to just the images in the open dialog box?)

Any ideas will greatly be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this to work. As appose to creating a variable called dialog_properties and assigning the default dialog properties prior to the click event, I moved the object to directly be properties for the dialog open box example:

```
  $(".popup_content .big_button").click(function() {

      popup_to_open = $(this).attr("rel");

      $("div[rel='"+popup_to_open+"']").dialog(
           {
               "width"   : "600",
               open    : function(event,ui) {
                   $('.resize_image').imgscale({
                         fade : 1000,
                         scale : "fill"
                   });
           }
      );
      return false;
  });
```

It appears this way the open event runs when the dialog opens where by creating a variable with the open event it runs prior to assigning the values. Not sure if that makes sense but it works :)